# "0" width for box renders as "1" width

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

When creating a box

```
new THREE.BoxGeometry(opening.geometry.xLength, opening.geometry.yLength, opening.geometry.zLength)
```

when you make a 0 width box.

```
new THREE.BoxGeometry(0, 1, 1)
```

It renders on the screen with 1 as width. I think it should not render anything. Is this a bug of threejs?.

Comment: This question might be better suited for the ThreeJs Github since it does seem to be a bug or undocumented expected behavior. My guess is that since `0` is a falsy value, it defaults to `1`, but that's just a guess.

Comment: Upon inspection, my guess was right [as seen here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/159a40648ee86755220491d4f0bae202235a341c/src/geometries/BoxGeometry.js#L55). A solution could be that if the width is `0` do not add the shape or remove it.

Comment: If you can confirm that is an expected behaviour I can mark your response as an answer.

Comment: That's the issue, I cannot confirm that it is the expected behavior, I can only analyze what happens behind the scene. Only the author (or collaborators) knows if it is meant to or not. Hence why opening a Github issue (with the line I referenced) is more suitable, you will have the best answer possible, and possibly the reasons behind such code.

Comment: if you want a box of 0 width, you can scale it `box.scale.set(0, 1, 1)`

Comment: @prisoner849 I create the box from a web service, so it sometimes comes as 0 when that particular dimension is not set yet. So the scale is not useful for that purpose.

Comment: Maybe makes sense to use `THREE.PlaneGeometry()`, when a dimension is 0.

Comment: Or set it to something tiny, like 0.0001, for example.

Comment: Isn't a box of size 0,1,1, still valid and should render like a plane? Try rendering 0,0,1 and you shuold see nothing.

Comment: That's my point. If that behaviour is not intentional. It should not render anything.

Comment: People says it is intentional, i have also posted on github. However the original creator has not said anything yet about it. imho renderng something the dimensions that you don't sent is not correct. However if i have no futher evidence I would like @Karl-AndréGagnon to post a answer to mark his as the one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three.js's current code is written such that 0 = use the default size of 1

You can work around it by making a size 1 box and scaling the geometry

```
const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(); // default is 1
geometry.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeScale(
    opening.geometry.xLength, opening.geometry.yLength, opening.geometry.zLength));
```

```js
'use strict';

/* global THREE */

function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});

  const fov = 75;
  const aspect = 2;  // the canvas default
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 5;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  camera.position.z = 2;

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color('white');

  function addLight(...pos) {
    const color = 0xFFFFFF;
    const intensity = 1;
    const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(color, intensity);
    light.position.set(...pos);
    scene.add(light);
  }
  addLight(-1, 2, 4);
  addLight( 2, 1, 4);

  const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
  geometry.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeScale(0, 1, 1));
  const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color:'red'});
  const box = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  scene.add(box);

  function resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
    const canvas = renderer.domElement;
    const width = canvas.clientWidth;
    const height = canvas.clientHeight;
    const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
    if (needResize) {
      renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    }
    return needResize;
  }

  function render(time) {
    time *= 0.001;

    if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
      const canvas = renderer.domElement;
      camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }

    box.rotation.x = time;
    box.rotation.y = time;

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

main();
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
#c { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display: block; }
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<script src="https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r105/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Doing so will result in a non-invertible normal matrix. You can't safely scale the geometry by 0. Also, FYI, see the method `Geometry.scale( x, y, z );`

Answer (score 1):

The dimensions passed to the constructor of `BoxGeometry` or `BoxBufferGeometry` must be positive.

three.js does not validate function, or constructor, arguments.

three.js r.106

Comment: 0 is non-negative. Do you know which person can confirm if this behaviour was intentional?.

Comment: Is there any chance if you could elaborate why is this important? You can hide the box once some condition is satisfied, you can create your own geometry, you can use planes etc. Why is this of such importance?